# Help With Dan Brown's Unsolved Puzzle

Tags: word, cipher

**Dan Brown has an unsolved message on his website https://danbrown.com/**

There are hidden symbols on 5 JPG images and 5 PNG images that overlay the JPGs.

JPG Images: [int1.bg.jpg](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int1.bg.jpg), [int2.bg.jpg](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int2.bg.jpg), [int3.bg.jpg](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int3.bg.jpg), [int4.bg.jpg](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int4.bg.jpg), [int5.bg.jpg](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int5.bg.jpg)

PNG Overlays: [int1.overlay.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int1.overlay.png), [int2.overlay.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int2.overlay.png), [int3.overlay.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int3.overlay.png), [int4.overlay.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int4.overlay.png), [int5.overlay.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/int5.overlay.png)

There is also an image named [secrets.img.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/db/secrets.img.png) which is overlaid by [job_38_11.png](https://danbrown.com/wp-content/themes/danbrown/images/job_38_11.png).

Here are the images with overlays applied:

**1**
[image: Image1]

**2**
[image: Image2]

**3**
[image: Image3]

**4**
[image: Image4]

**5**
[image: Image5]

---

The symbols used are Alchemical Symbols from the book DRACULUM and can be found here: https://archive.org/details/b30522535/page/n3/mode/2up

The graphics Dan Brown used seem to have come from the alchemical processes true type font which can be found here: https://www.alchemywebsite.com/alchemical_processes_symbols.html

These symbols are also used in the 2012 Gravity Falls series and can be found in the journals:

[image: Gravity Falls Journal 3]

Each symbol can be translated into a letter by using the font:

[image: Alchemical Processes Font]

---

All of the answers can be data mined from the website:

```
function checkAnswer(ans){
var rewards = {
    'fibonacci': 'tH5irgWopBM',
    'pythagorean': 'QTkbNcJaW88',
    'voynich':'Jl-DH4mvDVI',
    'dna':'q5t1-6xyz5U'
    };
var correctAnswers = {
    'fibonacci': 'fibonacci',
    'fibonacci sequence': 'fibonacci',
    '01123581321345589': 'fibonacci',
    '0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89': 'fibonacci',
    '144': 'fibonacci',
    'tetractys': 'pythagorean',
    'pythagoras': 'pythagorean',
    'tetrad':'pythagorean',
    'voynich manuscript': 'voynich',
    'voynich':'voynich',    
    'all worlds vanish': 'dna',
    'transform dna now': 'dna'
    };
```

The message decoded is 'all worlds vanish' and/or 'transform dna now'. The answers lead to 4 different YouTube videos:

**fibonacci:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tH5irgWopBM

**pythagorean:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTkbNcJaW88

**voynich:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl-DH4mvDVI

**And the final solution 'dna':** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5t1-6xyz5U

The final solution video makes a reference to Bertrand Zobrist: https://danbrown.fandom.com/wiki/Bertrand_Zobrist

---

Here's some information corresponding to each image:

**1**

[image: ImageInfo1]

**2**

[image: ImageInfo2]

**3**

[image: ImageInfo3]

**4**

[image: ImageInfo4]

**5**

[image: ImageInfo5]

There are 2 symbols that are not included in the DRACULUM book nor in the font:

[image]

The first seems to be a reference to a Masonic Pigpen Cipher. What's the second symbol? I'm assuming it's a null character.

If you omit these 2 symbols and substitute symbol for font character, you get the following string:

**wVxWPULCrAGwPLO = 15 characters**

AllWorldsVanish = 15 characters

TransformDNAnow = 15 characters

**But how do you get from wVxWPULCrAGwPLO to AllWorldsVanish/TransformDNAnow ?**

---

**Possible Alphabet / Clue:**

Job 38:11: when I said, 'This far you may come and no farther; here is where your proud waves halt'?

**Possible Keywords:**

symbols, adept, symbolsareveryadept, truth, hiding, athidingthetruth, roseline, TheSecretDoor, symbolsareveryadept, symbolsareveryadeptathidingthetruth, ordoabchao, orderfromchaos, chaos, fibonacci, fibonaccisequence, thefibonaccisequence, goldenspiral, goldenratio, ms408yalelibrary,
voynich, voynichmanuscript, thevoynichmanuscript, thepathisalive, thepathisalivecluesarehidden, thepathisalivecluesarehiddeninplainsight, arago, francoisarago, tetractys, tetrad, tarty, tartysect, pythagoreantheorem, pythagoras, silas, simon, ghost, Metatron, Metatron's cube, JOB 38:11, APPLE
Bertrand Zobrist

**Possible Solution?**

I thought I was onto something when I discovered data encryption using Pythagorean Triples. This is encryption which uses the Fibonacci sequence AND the Pythagorean Theorem: http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2014/WCE2014_pp516-519.pdf

However I did write a program to encrypt/decrypt using this method and I still did not crack the code.

Perhaps each page uses a different Vigenere Cipher / Keyword? https://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher

Perhaps it's using some other cipher perhaps similar to Gravity Falls? https://gravityfalls.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_cryptograms

**Additional Info**

I rearranged the message using Dan Brown's Magic Square method using Durer's magic square, as in The Lost Symbol: **OxVWPrALC_UGWLPW** (_ = null)

I put all the background symbols first (bg1, bg2, bg3...) and then added the PNG symbols at the end (png1, png2, png3):

Overlay symbols: V PZ L AGWP O

Background symbols: w xW U cr L

Combined: wVxWP_ULCrAGwPLO

**Can you help solve the cipher and explain how to arrive at "AllWorldsVanish" or "TransformDNAnow"?**